# Global constants in separate file. Is it a good idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constants

I'm currently working on ASP.NET MVC application.  I'm planning to create a static class where I plan to hold all the global string constants like session names.

The reason I'm hesitant is because it's kind of smell but I'm not aware of better alternative.

Please show me the light how to define global constants.

Comment: For what is worth, it does not smell bad to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vadim,

i do exactly as you propose and use a static class for this purpose. You then get the advantage of strongly typed accessors PLUS the ability to add overrides (in the form of methods), should you require them.

here's a snippet:

```
public static class Config
{
    private const string NotSet = "**VALUE NOT SET**";
    private const int pageSize = 5;

    public static string CustomCache
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomCache"] ?? NotSet;
        }
    }

    public static int PageSize
    {
        get
        {
            // simple default - no setter
            return pageSize; 
        }
    }
}
```

typical usage:

```
items = _repository.GetPaged(pageNumber, Config.PageSize)
```

in the above class, some settings are called '2nd generation' from the app settings in the web.config but with strong typing in the classes to ensure runtime error checking etc.. others are purely static settings defined in the class.

it's the flexibility to do all of the above that (in my opinion) gives this approach both appeal and a real strength.

Comment: As far as I see, CustomCache retrieves values from web.config and if there is no config, returns NotSet value described in the class. In addition to this, the other constant values can be assigned here and used directly as PageSize property. All that true?

Comment: correct - you could of course assign public string constants and get the benefit of strong typing on them. can't believe this answer was from almsot 5 yrs ago - where did it all go :)

Comment: :) Good. I have a similar problem on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255539/using-constant-for-defining-property-format-in-mvc/30255752?noredirect=1#comment48615812_30255752 and as far as I see from the answers, I am not sure if the approach above is suitable for my need i.e. runtime, compile time status. Could you check my question please? On the other hand, I can also think of using readonly instead of constant if it much more suitable for me. Could you clarify me please? (you can post your code on that page). Thanks...

Comment: Any help please regarding to this issue?

Comment: Hello again - I haven't really given it much thought or use beyond what I did above a few years back. I tend now to use xml config files for static data. these configs literally contain a serialised version of the class that is hydrated out into the application. this again gives you strong typing and imho is a more flexible approach as the values in the config can be changed without having to recompile the application.

Comment: if you have any queries, just drop a quick comment and i'll answer as time permits... good luck

Comment: Thanks, you are so helpful. Actually I want to create a separate class and populate constant (static) values in it. The problem is that, I will also use some values of this class in my model as DataFormatString ("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"). So, trying to apply your code above results error due to compiling time problem (I think due to using the values in model class). So, if you have any idea about how to fix it, I would be happy if you clarify me.

Comment: ok, quick thought, why not create a static class and extend the DateTime object (as an extension method that returns `0:dd/MM/yyyy`). that way, your model will still contain the proper dates, but onl;y the presentational elements will run thro the extension method.

Comment: Of course it seems to be much more prettier and I can override DisplayFormatAttribute by creating this static class. But, actually I also want to keep all the constant values in a class and for this reason I asked my last question. Nevertheless, if it is not logical I can apply the opt you mentioned of course.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to create a resources (.resx) file. Or if these are configurable values, they can go in web.config or a database configuration table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global.asax file for this purpose - I would use accessors for them e.g.

```
private static int var ;

public static int VAR
{
   get { return var ; }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a big difference between putting constants in global.asax or another class.  Can you tell me if there's an advantage of putting constants in global.asax?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is MVC or Web forms, I use a combination of database entries (for site settings that can be modified by dashboard) and web.config appSettings (for site settings that do not change often or at all, i.e. constant).

Comment: In my case I don't expect the value of the constants to be changed at all.  I don't see a big difference between appSettings or a separate static class.  Let me know if I'm missing something.