# Using constant for defining property format in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, static, constants, date-format

In  my MVC application I have many properties of **DateTime** datatype and I define DataFormatString on every new property in this datatype is defined as below:

**Model:**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }


[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime EndDate{ get; set; }
```

Instead of this, I think there is another option to define these DataFormatStrings for just one place and at once by creating a new class containing constant value or using web config, etc. So, in this case what is the best way to use constant values i.e. date format, etc. I use globalization string on my web.config, but I am not sure defining date DataFormatStrings in web.config as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'd opt for a custom attribute

```
public class ShortDateFormatAttribute : DisplayFormatAttribute
{
    public ShortDateFormatAttribute()
    {
        DateFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
        ApplyFormatInEditMode = true;
    }
}
....
[ShortDateFormat]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
[ShortDateFormat]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I also want to use this format for the other properties in the other models (in other class file). So, what should I do in that case? Create a new class file for defining constant values?

Comment: @H.Johnson then you re-use the same attribute, that's the point. Attributes aren't specific to one model they can be reused.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the point that you define a custom property. I will try and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Overriding is a good idea, but I preferred to use create a class for all of the other constants. So, I voted up your answer, thanks a lot...

Comment: @H.Johnson you can still create a constant and just reference it in the attribute...`DateFormat = MyConstants.ShortDateFormat`. Not really seeing why you think this wouldn't work?

Comment: No, I did not mean that this did not work and that's why I voted up your answer. Ok, your method can also be used as the other approach. But creating a dedicated static class seems to be better to me as indicated on (jim tollan"s answer) on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433058/global-constants-in-separate-file-is-it-a-good-idea

Comment: @H.Johnson my point is these are 2 completely separate issues you are talking about. Moving all your format strings into a global static class is fine, however, it simply means you are swapping out your hardcoded string for another reference so it doesn't really reduce the amount of code you need to write (I presumed that's what your original problem was?). The point of using a custom attribute means you just reference it once and reuse it (regardless if it's a constant or not), on top of that it reduces the amount of code you need to write and increases readability.

Comment: I want to create a separate class for defining constant value and use them for entire solution in my MVC application as as indicated on (jim tollan"s answer) on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433058/global-constants-in-separate-file-is-it-a-good-idea But, I am not sure which approach would be best for me. Could you please update your answer similar to jim tollan"s answer if it suitable for my needs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help pls? I am waiting for your code sample by updating your answer. Thanks...

Comment: @H.Johnson I've already explained why the answer you are linking too and your question are 2 separate issues. Move your constant values into a static helper all you like, however, you would still need to reference this on every attribute e.g. `[DisplayFormat(DateFormat = Const.ShortDateFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`, the benefit of my answer is it encompasses all that, it's only required to be configured once and then it's re-used on all the properties. I've already explained all this, I am beginning to think your either confused or your question is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, I was really so confused. For your answer I do not need to use the line [DisplayFormat(DateFormat = Const.ShortDateFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] on every new property definition. In addition to this, what if I want to use constant values in my MVC application? How should  I create a new class and use it? Could you please update your answer that also shows this situation? Many thanks again...

Comment: @H.Johnson I'm not sure I understand what you m ean by *"what if I want to use constant values in my MVC application?"* - that's completely irrelevant to the attributes. As I mentioned, if you want to have a static helper then by all means have one (like the one you keep referencing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433058/global-constants-in-separate-file-is-it-a-good-idea)).

Comment: The problem is that, I do not want to create a separate class for every attribute. So, I create a folder called Custom and create a new class called Attributes. Now I need to create ShortDateFormatAttribute in this class, but I am not sure how to define this properly (which one is static, which one is public, constructor definition, etc.). So, could you please update your code with this information? After that I will apply your method and inform you if it works. Many thanks again for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation that you are facing here - attribute parameters can be only compile-time ones. Because of this you have two options:

1. Just define a constant and use it in all the models, like this

   ```
   private const string DateFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";

   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = DateFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   ```
2. Define the format in web.config and create your own attribute, perhaps inheriting from `DisplayFormat`, that will go to web.config to retrieve necessary data. Should be really simple - you just need another constructor that will get format param from web.config. Something like that:

   ```
   public class WebConfigDateDisplayFormatAttribute : DisplayFormatAttribute
   {
       public WebConfigDateDisplayFormatAttribute()
       {
           DataFormat = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateFormat"];
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for help and information. I think the first way is better for me, but I also want to use this format for the other properties in the other models (in other class file). So, what should I do in that case? Create a new class file for defining constant values? Or is it not possible?

Comment: You can declare your constant public or internal, which will make it available for other classes. And yes, you can even have a dedicated class to hold all your constants

Comment: I see another approach (jim tollan"s answer) on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433058/global-constants-in-separate-file-is-it-a-good-idea Can I apply your answer as this?

Comment: @H.Johnson, unfortunately you won't be able to use it for #1 in the answer, because this is still not a compile time thing. But this is a nice way to encapsulate your dependency on settings file if you opt to #2.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think you meant that the changes I make in the Config class (for case #1 in your answer) only takes effect after building the project. Otherwise, the changes will not take effect. On the other hand, the changes made in the web.config will take effect immediately. Do you meant this? If so, there is no problem, I can use jim tollan"s answer for my model and I can build the project after every changes of Config class. Is there any problem doing this?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Compile time means that value should be known at compile (build) time. Constants, literals are such things. Config file and values from it, no matter how you organize its reading, are only available on run time, when you actually run the program, and therefore cannot be used as attribute ctor arguments. Does it make sense?

Comment: I am really so confused as I do not have enough idea about Compile & run time. Could you please clarify me a little bit more? Thanks...

Comment: Could you please update your answer for a similar approach to  jim tollan"s answerby updating your answer?

Comment: What bout using ReadOnly instead of constant? If it solves the problem you described, you can give your sample code by using ReadOnly. Any idea?

Comment: @H.Johnson, sorry, no again, readonly fields can be changed in constructor, so again runtime and not compile time. You have to deal in constants if you would like to go down path #1

Comment: Ok. In that case I should create a new Class and define static values (constants) as you defined above. But, I have to define the values as public, not private. Is that true?

Comment: @H.Johnson, yes, if you want them shared, or in a separate class - public, or internal (slightly better)